# Azure object does not exist in the current context Home/Index

Tags: c#, html, azure, object, compiler-errors

An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to process this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

/home/site/wwwroot/Views/Home/Index.cshtml

```
The name 'localizer' does not exist in the current context
+
        <h1 class="display-4">@Html.Raw(""+@localizer.Get("Welcome")+"")</h1>
The name 'localizer' does not exist in the current context
+
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="@localizer.Get("Search") @localizer.Get("Client").ToLower()">
The name 'localizer' does not exist in the current context
+
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="@localizer.Get("Search") @localizer.Get("Client").ToLower()">
The name 'localizer' does not exist in the current context
+
            @Html.Raw(""+@localizer.Get("Specific")+"")</button>
The name 'localizer' does not exist in the current context
+
            @Html.Raw(""+@localizer.Get("Others")+"")</button>
The name 'localizer' does not exist in the current context
+
<h3>@localizer.Get("General")</h3>
The name 'localizer' does not exist in the current context
+
<h3>@localizer.Get("Specific")</h3>
The name 'localizer' does not exist in the current context
+
<h3>@localizer.Get("Others")</h3>
```

localizer used at _ViewImports.cshtml
''
@inject weblogint2.Resources.CommonLocalization localizer
''

I have also tried to put this on Home/index but getting same problem.

When running on localhost its works fine. what is causing the problem.

''''

```
#pragma warning disable 1591
[assembly: global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorCompiledItemAttribute(typeof(AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index), @"mvc.1.0.view", @"/Views/Home/Index.cshtml")]
namespace AspNetCore
{
    #line hidden
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
    [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorSourceChecksumAttribute(@"SHA1", @"4e57af940c7d6ad36f83f153e6981200ed9e3f2e", @"/Views/Home/Index.cshtml")]
    public class Views_Home_Index : global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<dynamic>
    {
        private static readonly global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute __tagHelperAttribute_0 = new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute("src", new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString("~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"), global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.HtmlAttributeValueStyle.DoubleQuotes);
        private static readonly global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute __tagHelperAttribute_1 = new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute("href", new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString("~/css/tabs.css"), global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.HtmlAttributeValueStyle.DoubleQuotes);
        private static readonly global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute __tagHelperAttribute_2 = new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute("rel", new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString("stylesheet"), global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.HtmlAttributeValueStyle.DoubleQuotes);
        private static readonly global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute __tagHelperAttribute_3 = new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute("src", new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString("~/jqGrid2016/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"), global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.HtmlAttributeValueStyle.DoubleQuotes);
        private static readonly global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute __tagHelperAttribute_4 = new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute("src", new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString("~/jqGrid2016/globalize.js"), global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.HtmlAttributeValueStyle.DoubleQuotes);
        private static readonly global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute __tagHelperAttribute_5 = new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute("href", new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString("~/jqGrid2016/ui.jqgrid-bootstrap.css"), global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.HtmlAttributeValueStyle.DoubleQuotes);
        private static readonly global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute __tagHelperAttribute_6 = new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute("href", new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString("~/jqGrid2016/ui.jqgrid.css"), global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.HtmlAttributeValueStyle.DoubleQuotes);
        private static readonly global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute __tagHelperAttribute_7 = new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute("href", new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString("~/jqGrid2016/ui.jqgrid-bootstrap-ui.css"), global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.HtmlAttributeValueStyle.DoubleQuotes);
        private static readonly global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute __tagHelperAttribute_8 = new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute("src", new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString("~/js/main.js"), global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.HtmlAttributeValueStyle.DoubleQuotes);
        private static readonly global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute __tagHelperAttribute_9 = new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute("src", new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString("~/js/client.js"), global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.HtmlAttributeValueStyle.DoubleQuotes);
        #line hidden
        #pragma warning disable 0649
        private global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext __tagHelperExecutionContext;
        #pragma warning restore 0649
        private global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner __tagHelperRunner = new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner();
        #pragma warning disable 0169
        private string __tagHelperStringValueBuffer;
        #pragma warning restore 0169
        private global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperScopeManager __backed__tagHelperScopeManager = null;
        private global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperScopeManager __tagHelperScopeManager
        {
            get
            {
                if (__backed__tagHelperScopeManager == null)
                {
                    __backed__tagHelperScopeManager = new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperScopeManager(StartTagHelperWritingScope, EndTagHelperWritingScope);
                }
                return __backed__tagHelperScopeManager;
            }
        }
        private global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.TagHelpers.UrlResolutionTagHelper __Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Razor_TagHelpers_UrlResolutionTagHelper;
        #pragma warning disable 1998
        public async override global::System.Threading.Tasks.Task ExecuteAsync()
        {
#nullable restore
#line 1 "/home/site/wwwroot/Views/Home/Index.cshtml"
  
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";


#line default
#line hidden
#nullable disable
            WriteLiteral("\r\n<div");
            BeginWriteAttribute("class", " class=\"", 150, "\"", 158, 0);
            EndWriteAttribute();
            WriteLiteral(">\r\n    <div class=\"text-center\">\r\n        <h1 class=\"display-4\">");
#nullable restore


#line 9 "/home/site/wwwroot/Views/Home/Index.cshtml"
                         Write(Html.Raw(""+@localizer.Get("Welcome")+""));
```

'''

Comment: can you check the framework configured in App Service --> Configuration --> General Settings --> Stack. It should be .Net Core

Comment: Yes it is .Net core

Comment: I have changed the publish profile. now its working fine.

Comment: good to hear that it's working